# JOptionPane.showInputDialog Makes my program crash

Tags: java, intellij-idea, crash, joptionpane

I've used this input dialog before but for some reason it is making my program crash. I've tried adding different options to the input dialog but i get the same results

The error message on Intelliji is "Process finished with exit code -805306369"

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(); 
String name = pane.showInputDialog("Name Your Profile");

SaveParameters(name);  //this is what takes the output
```

Comment: Please post the code of method 'SaveParameters'

Comment: Are any exceptions thrown?

Comment: No exceptions, It is windows that tells me that the JVM has crashed.

Comment: I removed the SaveParameters(name); line and it still crashes

Comment: crashed means after entering some value or before itself?

Comment: if the problem appeared suddenly, maybe you can try to clean your project: got to File\Invalidate Caches

Comment: The InputDialog doesn't even appear It crashes as soon as the button is clicked. I have tried putting it directly in the ActionEvent method and also having it in a void method being called by the ActionEvent method but it makes no difference.

Comment: restart your IntelliJ IDEA IDE and then clean and Build your application.

Comment: Solved. The window was appearing behind my intellji and the program. If i tried to alt-tab or click to change windows it would crash. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized this was caused by the window displaying behind my main UI, which caused the UI to crash when i  clicked to focus the main UI again.

Giving a null argument to the Component argument fixes the problem.

```
String Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Name Your Profile");
```